# How to add Null value to match the columns in UNION CAKEPHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-4.x, sql-null

NULL this give me SQL syntax when trying to match the number of columns in first table but 0 works fine instead of NULL

Sample code

```
    $a = $table_a
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])


    $b = $table_b
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'first_name', NULL])


    $union = $b->union($a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you cannot use PHP `NULL` in the select list, as the value is being used in string concatenation when compiling the SQL, and PHP will convert `NULL` to an empty string.

You can either use an alias and `NULL` as a string, eg:

```php
->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name' => 'NULL'])
```

or an expression object that allows you to insert raw SQL directly and omit the alias:

```php
->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
    return [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        $query->newExpr('NULL'),
        // in the first query the alias would be required
        // 'last_name' => $query->newExpr('NULL'),
    ];
})
```

Note that you can only omit the alias in the query that is being passed to `union()`, you cannot omit it in the first query, as the ORM needs column names later on when it builds the result set, omitting the alias in the first query would result in an error!